# NPM CLI application relative path doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm creating a CLI application in NodeJS and the package is going to be published on NPM. The application is very simple as it has only two files. Here is the structure of application:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mycliapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some description",
  "main": "./bin/cli.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "mycliapp": "bin/cli.js"
  },
}
```

**bin/cli.js**

```
const nodePlop    = require('node-plop');
const configPath  = './bin/config.js';
const plop = nodePlop(configPath, {
 force: argv.force || argv.f
});
```

**bin/config.js**

```
{
  // some configuration
}
```

Now if I create symlink with `npm install -g` from this directory and run the command `mycliapp` from the same development directory, it works absolutely fine but if I run this `mycliapp` command from any other directory in my computer, the `const configPath  = './bin/config.js'` is tried to be taken from the current working directory not from the actual npm package and hence the config file is not found.

How can I solve this issue? I tried using `__dirname` and `__filename` with `path.join` but nothing seems to be working.

I also published this package on npm and installed from there, the same issue is occurring.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON in your `package.json` is malformed -- you should remove the trailing comma after you set the `bin` parameter.

Also, if your configuration file is in the same directory as your script, you should reference it within your script as `./config.js`.

Finally, you need to include a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env node`) at the top of your `cli.js` file or any file you intend to use as your point of entry into the app so that your system knows what interpreter to use to execute the file.

See [this post](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm) on the npm blog for more information.

Comment: its not working the way you told. the structure of my published npm package would be my-package/bin/cli.js and I guess the bin script runs from my-package

Comment: The only issue I've is config file not found even if it present there